# Optimize search result by sending few/less requests to backend from React UI

Tags: javascript, axios

I am sending request to backend on users input in Input Field, I have already implemented debouncing even though, my UI is lagging little bit, what can I do/implement along with debouncing to improve search results.

Actually backend search is very heavy call, are there any other ways/tricks/techniques which I can use to improve it further

[My backend is taking about 1500ms to 4000ms to process request as number of records are more than 100000]

Comment: Please share more information about what the frontend/backend is doing in this request. You are sending 100,000 records to the search? Or back as results? Or you are searching them to find the results?

Answer (score 0):

Using axios cancelToken feature was very helpful, if the response of the first request arrives after the response of the second request, then we might render inconsistent data.

```
import axios from "axios"
import React from "react"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  let cancelToken
  const handleSearchChange = async e => {
    const searchTerm = e.target.value

    //Check if there are any previous pending requests
    if (typeof cancelToken != typeof undefined) {
      cancelToken.cancel("Operation canceled due to new request.")
    }

    //Save the cancel token for the current request
    cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source()

    try {
      const results = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:4000/animals?q=${searchTerm}`,
        { cancelToken: cancelToken.token } //Pass the cancel token to the current request
      )
      console.log("Results for " + searchTerm + ": ", results.data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "3em", textAlign: "center" }}>
      <input
        style={{ width: "60%", height: "1.5rem" }}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={handleSearchChange}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```